# How can I style an autoform in Meteoric?

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, meteor-autoform, meteoric

```
  {{#autoForm schema="asdf" id="sdfg" type="method" meteormethod="meth"}}
    <fieldset>
      {{> afQuickField name="startLocation"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="destination"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="date"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="departureTime"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="returnTime"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="seats" type="number"}}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit<button>
  {{/autoForm}}
```

The above code generates a form in my Meteor app, however it looks pretty bad (or at least, non-intuitive):

[image]

I don't know why this is. In the examples ([1](http://autoform.meteor.com/insertaf), [2](http://autoform.meteor.com/insertaf)) I'm looking at, the form renders in a much more sensical way. How can I get the afQuickField to show the label and the input on separate lines, or at least in another way that makes sense?

Comment: there's probably no need to put it in a fieldset

Comment: Have you added the `meteoric:autoform-ionic` package? https://github.com/meteoric/autoform-ionic

Comment: @challett @corvid taking out `fieldset` doesn't change anything, and `meteoric:autoform-ionic` has been added